# Twitter bootstrap carousel slideshow with js code

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I want to make a slideshow of a bunch of js/css animation on a site. I am using bootstrap as a framework of it. The Carousel sounds like a built in function for slideshow in slideshow but seems like it is for images. Mine is js animation and I found hard time dealing with it. Is there better way doing it based on bootstrap framework?

This is Carousel in bootstrap:

```
<!--  Carousel - consult the Twitter Bootstrap docs at 
      http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel -->
<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
  <!--  Next and Previous controls below
        href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

What I am trying to do but messed things up:

Answer (score 0):

You can use active the slider with `$('.carousel').carousel();` and on each slide you can use your js/css effects with

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
 // js function etc.
});
```

For example http://jsbin.com/kekocuha/1 , I used animate css for text animations for each slide, you can use your images js etc. like that too